# Using SQL to compare tables

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison

My manager has asked me to compile a report to compare the column names of the following two tables:

- UK Staff
- USA Staff

So he's not looking for any data inside the tables, just a piece of SQL that we can run to check the column names and show the columns whose name is not in both databases. A piece of SQL code or stored procedure would be fine.

I've only been a DBA now for a few months, and i'm not sure where to get started with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Im using Oracle, sorry i forgot to include it.

Comment: My manager called it a "report" of some kind.

Comment: For example, if both tables had 100 columns each that were the same, they wouldnt show. Only the columns that were not replicated in the other table. So duplicate column names dont show.

Comment: I want duplicate column names hidden.

Comment: Just the column names.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, you can do a full outer join of two subqueries against `all_tab_columns`, or `user_tab_columns` if you own them both:

```
select usa.column_name as usa_column, uk.column_name as uk_column
from (
  select column_name from all_tab_columns
  where table_name = '<USA_TABLE_NAME>'
) usa
full outer join (
  select column_name from all_tab_columns
  where table_name = '<UK_TABLE_NAME>'
) uk
on uk.column_name = usa.column_name
order by nvl(usa.column_name, uk.column_name), uk.column_name;
```

That shows columns that appear in both. To hide those just add:

```
where usa.column_name is null or uk.column_name is null
```

... before the `order by`.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31f1f/1). (Or [with Gordon's approach](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31f1f/4) for the same example).

Of course you can then build on that to present the differences however you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is amazing, In my mind, I just has a simple select distinct query in mind. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The table/view that contains the metadata information in Oracle is `all_tab_cols`.

Here is an example of how you might compare the columns in both:

```
select column_name,
       (case when max(case when table_name = 'table1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 'InTable2'
             when max(case when table_name = 'table2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 'InTable1'
             else 'InBoth'
        end) as which
from all_tab_cols
where table_name in ('table1', 'table2')
group by column_name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a lot of help. I now understand the structure in which I can write this query, and similar queries.